# How to read and see the Binary file

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, c#-to-vb.net

This is what my code looks like:

```
System.IO.BinaryWriter output;
System.IO.TextReader input;
System.IO.FileStream fs = new
System.IO.FileStream(this.txtOutputFileName.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
output = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs);
input = System.IO.File.OpenText(this.txtSourceFileName.Text);
string SourceProgram = input.ReadToEnd();
input.Close();
output.Write('B');
output.Write('3');
output.Write('2');
```

Now i would like to print the values written using the `MessageBox.Show()` Method.
If i create an object say `System.IO.BinaryReader readoutput` - how do i go about achieving my task??

Remember i simply want to verify 'B', '3', '2' are being written properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call output.Close() and then open/read that file the same way you do here with 'input' and 'SourceProgram'

Answer (score 0):

you could try the `BinaryReader` this way:

```
output.Close();

var readStream = new FileStream(this.txtOutputFileName.Text, FileMode.Open);

BinaryReader readBinary = new BinaryReader(readStream);

var msg = readBinary.ReadString();

MessageBox.Show(msg);

readStream.Close();
```